# PowerBI: Is there a workaround to create a slicer with a measure?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a table that I added 2 columns to in dashboard view that have Y and N values. These columns are from 2 measures that I created. It was unable to be done with calculated columns since it was based off another table that is not related to it.

Is there a way to create a slicer on the dashboard so the user can look at just Y or N values of these measures?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Not directly. If these values are static then easiest would be to have them as Calculated Columns. Otherwise it is possible but indirectly, meaning you can have you measures look at a separate table/slicer selected values and then only return a value if true. Update your question with a little more detail and share the expressions used. It should be possible to add as Calculated Columns regardless of relationships.